# Geeting invalid_cast_argument error in Athena (Presto)

Tags: presto

i am quite new at sql, i am trying a simple query

```
select
        *,
        max(cast(version_date as date)) over (partition by id) mx_dt,
        min(cast(version_date as date)) over (partition by id) min_dt
    from "raw_data"."raw_brands";
```

but i am getting this error :

An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Value cannot be cast to date: 2020-01-16 19:09:25.086223

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some approaches.

1. Use [date_parse](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#date_parse) function.

```
presto> select date_parse('2020-01-16 19:09:25.086223', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f');
          _col0
-------------------------
 2020-01-16 19:09:25.086
```

and then cast to date.

```
presto> select date(date_parse('2020-01-16 19:09:25.086223', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f'));
   _col0
------------
 2020-01-16

presto> select cast(date_parse('2020-01-16 19:09:25.086223', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f') as date);
   _col0
------------
 2020-01-16
```

2. Use [substr](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/string.html#substr) function

```
presto> select cast(substr('2020-01-16 19:09:25.086223', 1, 10) as date);
   _col0
------------
 2020-01-16
```